# Android studio not working while creating new project

Tags: android-studio

I do not know why android studio is not working .
When I try to create new project it shows following screen.
How to fix this issue?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please open File | Settings | Plugins and make sure the Android plugin is enabled.